# How can I change the color of the project view?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've been struggling to find how to change the background color of the project view?

I'm using 2016.3 on a mac.

Comment: What **exactly** you wish to change there? Please show a screenshot with arrows pointing to such elements. Generally speaking -- it's part of the GUI Theme ... so cannot really be changed on its own via Settings/Preferences (only together with GUI Theme). At the same time you may try "Color Tree" or "Color Ide" plugins (old plugins -- no idea if they still work with latest IDE versions (but should))

Comment: Well, I'd like to change the background color of everything. I know how to do this for the code view but not for the menus or project view.

Comment: Well .. as I have said -- those parts are handled by GUI Theme (a.k.a. Look & Feel in Java Swing apps) which you can change at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance --> Theme`. Color for such area alone is not customisable. You can also try those 2 plugins -- they will affect Tree View areas (accordingly to their description).